# Не понимаю почему не отрисовывается Mesh?

Tags: c#, unity3d, геометрия

В коде генерируется хекс грид. Все расчеты вроде правильные, но вот в самой игре текстура не отрисовывается. Может кто то сможет найти ошибку, потому что я ее не вижу.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class HexRender : MonoBehaviour
{ List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
List<int> triangles = new List<int>();
List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();
private Mesh _mesh;
private MeshFilter _meshFilter;
private MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;
private List<Face> _faces;
public Material Material;
public float innerSize;
public float outerSize;
public float height;

public bool isFlatTopped;
private int point = 1;
private void Awake()
{
    _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    _meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    _mesh = new Mesh();
    _mesh.name = "hex";
    _meshFilter.mesh = _mesh;
 
    _meshRenderer.material = Material;
}
public struct Face
{
    public List<Vector3> vertices { get; private set; }
    public List<int> triangles { get; private set; }
    public List<Vector2> uvs { get; private set; }

    public Face(List<Vector3> vertices, List<int> triangles, List<Vector2> uvs)
    {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.triangles = triangles;
        this.uvs = uvs;
    }
}

private void OnEnable()
{


DrawMesh();          

}


 //public void OnValidate()
 // {
 //     if (Application.isPlaying)
  //    {
  //        DrawMesh();
  //    }
 // }

public void DrawMesh()
{
    DrawFaces();

    CombineFaces();

}

private void DrawFaces()
{
    _faces = new List<Face>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _faces.Add(CreateFace(innerSize, outerSize, height / 2f, height / 2f, i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _faces.Add(CreateFace(innerSize, outerSize, -height / 2f, -height / 2f, i, true));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _faces.Add(CreateFace(innerSize, innerSize, height / 2f, height / 2f, i, true));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _faces.Add(CreateFace(outerSize, outerSize, height / 2f, height / 2f, i, false));
    }
}

private void CombineFaces()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < _faces.Count; i++)
    {
        vertices.AddRange(_faces[i].vertices);
        uvs.AddRange(_faces[i].uvs);

        int offset = (4 * i);
        foreach (int tris in _faces[i].triangles)
        {
            triangles.Add(tris + offset);
        }
    }

    Debug.Log(vertices[0]);
    _mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
   Debug.Log(_mesh);
   _mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
    _mesh.uv = uvs.ToArray();
    _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}

private Face CreateFace(float innerRad, float outerRad, float SideA, float SideB, int point, bool reverse = false)
{
    Vector3 pointA = GetPoint(innerRad, SideB, point);
    Vector3 pointB = GetPoint(innerRad, SideB, (point < 5) ? point + 1 : 0);
    Vector3 pointC = GetPoint(outerRad, SideA, (point < 5) ? point + 1 : 0);
    Vector3 pointD = GetPoint(outerRad, SideA, point);
    List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>() {pointA, pointB, pointC, pointD};
    List<int> triangles = new List<int>() {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0};
    List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>()
    {
        new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1, 0), new Vector2(1, 1),
        new Vector2(0, 1)
    };
    if (reverse)
    {
        vertices.Reverse();
    }
    return new Face(vertices,triangles,uvs);
}

protected Vector3 GetPoint(float size, float height, int index)
{
    float angle_deg = isFlatTopped ? 60 * index : 60 * index - 30;
    float angle_rag = Mathf.PI / 180f * angle_deg;
    return new Vector3((size * Mathf.Cos(angle_rag)), height, (size * Mathf.Sin(angle_rag)));
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Сгенерированный меш не присвоин рендерингу.

---

Это как с материалом:

```
MeshRenderer.material = targetMaterial;
```

Если изменить `targetMaterial`, то отображаемый материал не измениться, поскольку в рендере копия а не ссылка. Для ссылки нужно указать:

```
MeshRenderer.sharedMaterial = MatX;
```

---

С мешем тоже самое, но помница в старых версия был баг и `sharedMesh` не работал, не знаю как сейчас.

Вообщем в конце генерации можно тупо обновить `MeshFilter`.